# How can I modify my hosts file? It is read-only and cannot be modified even as Adminstrator.

Tags: permissions, hosts, read-only

Does anyone know how to modify entries on the hosts file when it is marked as read-only?

I have tried unchecking the `Read-only` tick box, but I get an `Access is Denied` error, and I'm running as the Administrator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't edit it in place. Take a copy of it, edit the copy and then replace the original with the edited copy. Doing all this as an administrator of course.

Always a good idea to keep a copy of the original version as well in case you need revert the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a personal machine, or in a corporate environment?  Is it possible that it's locked down thru SMS so you're not allowed to change it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to change permissions or attributes on a file you can [take ownership](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421) of the file to force the changes to be made.