# Windows 8.1 Single Language: Access is denied (hosts file and registry)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, permissions, windows-registry, hosts

Just switched from windows 7 to 8.1 (New machine scanned for viruses, Antivirus temporary disabled) and discovered that windows doesn't allow access to large amount of its files that were easily accessed in its previous version, such as hosts file, giving error "Access is Denied". After searching the internet it seems that there are workarounds around this problem, but none of them worked for me, for example:

1) Destination folder access denied (You need permission to perform this action) error while trying to copy and replace hosts file with modified one;

2) Access is denied error while trying to open notepad as administrator and then open and modify hosts file in it.

The main problem lies not in disability to modify hosts file, but that some vital software, such as Denwer, doesnt work without accessing it. Running it as administrator doesn't help either.

I was also not able to modify registry editor keys (in my case EnableLUA key value to 0), I keep getting error "Cannot edit EnableLUA: Error writing the values new contents." although I am by default granted Full Control to modify it, I was not even able to change my permissions getting Access is denied error. No workaround I could find worked for me.

Maybe I am missing something and there is a way to overcome this annoying issue that makes work virtually impossible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running an anti virus program that blocks access to the hosts file?

Comment: Antivirus is disabled while i am trying to modify it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I modify my hosts file? It is read-only and cannot be modified even as Adminstrator.](http://superuser.com/questions/124888/how-can-i-modify-my-hosts-file-it-is-read-only-and-cannot-be-modified-even-as-a)

Comment: As I already mentioned that method of copying did not work for me, so no, it should be different issue.